# NullPointerException in servlet GooglePlus

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, google-plus, scribe

I'm using scribe java ( https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/GoogleExample.java) to  sign in on GooglePlus. I use 2 servlet, one for the login, the other it's the callback. When I call the signin's servlet, it's ok, but when Google Plus redirects me to the callback servlet, I got a nullPointer Exception. This error is caused by session's attribute, because i use this session attribute to store my tokens. I do a setAttribute in my servlet login and I do a getAttribute in the callback, but it's null.

My code is as bellow : 
Servlet login :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String API_KEY = "******************";
    String API_SECRET = "**********";
    String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read";

    InfosGooglePlus infos = new InfosGooglePlus();
    infos.setApiKey(API_KEY);
    infos.setApiSecret(API_SECRET);
    infos.setScope(SCOPE);

    String redirect = Channel.getChannel().getUrl();
    if (Util.notEmpty(request.getParameter("redirect"))) {
        redirect = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("redirect"));
    }

    request.getSession().setAttribute("redirectGooglePlus", redirect);

    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(GoogleApi.class).apiKey(API_KEY).apiSecret(API_SECRET).scope(SCOPE)
            .callback("http://127.0.0.1:8080/cci/callbackGooglePlus").build();

    Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

    String token = requestToken.getToken();
    String tokenSecret = requestToken.getSecret();


    request.getSession().setAttribute("token", token);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("tokenSecret", tokenSecret);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("infosGooglePlus", infos);

    response.sendRedirect(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));

}
```

And my callback servlet :

```
InfosGooglePlus infos = (InfosGooglePlus) request.getSession().getAttribute("infosGooglePlus");

String redirect = Channel.getChannel().getUrl();
if (Util.notEmpty(request.getSession().getAttribute("redirectGooglePlus"))) {
    redirect = URLDecoder.decode((String) request.getSession().getAttribute("redirectGooglePlus"));
}
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(GoogleApi.class)
        .apiKey(infos.getApiKey()).apiSecret(infos.getApiSecret()).scope(infos.getScope())
        .build();

String oauth_verifier = request.getParameter("oauth_verifier");

Token requestToken = infos.getRequestToken();
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, new Verifier(oauth_verifier));

String url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/";
OAuthRequest requestOauth = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, url);
requestOauth.addQuerystringParameter("format", "json");
service.signRequest(accessToken, requestOauth);
Response responseOath = requestOauth.send();

int resp = responseOath.getCode();
String rep = responseOath.getBody();
System.out.println(resp);
System.out.println(rep);
System.out.println("Test ok");
infos.setOauth_verifier(oauth_verifier);
infos.setAccessToken(accessToken);

request.getSession().setAttribute("infosGooglePlus", infos);

response.sendRedirect(redirect);
```

Thanks for the help !

[EDIT]
I got the error at this line :

```
 OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder().provider(GoogleApi.class).apiKey(infos.getApiKey()).apiSecret(infos.getApiSecret()).scope(infos.getScope())
    .build();
```

And the stacktrace is :

```
    avr. 29, 2014 1:08:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    Grave: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet callbackGooglePlus a généré une exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at fr.wyniwyg.timelineplugin.oauth.servlet.GetTimelineGooglePlusServlet.doGet(GetTimelineGooglePlusServlet.java:83)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.jalios.jcms.servlet.FriendlyURLFilter.doFilter(FriendlyURLFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: which line exactly produce nullpointer?

Comment: Please add the call to your code with parameter values and the error (stack trace will do best) you get from it.

Comment: because you using two servlet and both are maintain different sessions you got null pointer.this is my opinion

Comment: you could check, if the sessionIds are equivalent in both servlets

Comment: I tested that, and sessionIds are not equivalent. But, why ?

Answer (score 0):

In your first stage, you're setting the token to the session object:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken);
```

but in the second stage, you're trying to get this out of the infos object:

```
Token requestToken = infos.getRequestToken();
```

Try getting it out of the session.

Finally, you call each one "a servlet". Are they actually different servlets, or are they the same servlet with different entry points? If they are different servlets, the sessions aren't shared between them unless you're saving the sessions to a shared store.

**Update**: As you've noted now, you're doing this in two different servlets. Servlet containers are supposed to isolate servlets from each other, so the sessions managed by one servlet are not shared with the other servlet.

You will either need to make them the same servlet (which you can do - same servlet, just multiple entry points to that servlet) or create a shared resource for the two servlets to use to coordinate their session objects or some other shared resource which you communicate with the client via cookies or other HTTP parameters.

Comment: The error appears before this line (Token requestToken =.......). But I made the change, thanks.
It's different servlets

Comment: Updated answer. The problem is that you're using multiple servlets.

Comment: I understand, but I do the same mecanicsm with Facebook and I don't have problems. And, when a personn goes to my localhost with his computer, they don't have NullPointerException.